# Will .NET framework release object earlier than the user close the form

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it ok to create and show forms like this?

```
private void settingsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var settingsForm = new SettingsForm();
    settingsForm.Show();
}
```

Won't .NET framework release this object earlier than the user close the form?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It will only get released when its no longer in use, however a settings form sounds like it should be modal (`ShowDialog`)

Comment: Yes it's OK; no it won't  I don't know the inner workings but there's got to be some object that holds a reference to the form while it's open.

Comment: Well, you can surely reason this out for yourself, .NET collecting an object while the user still interacts with it would make a spectacular bang.  Control objects, like Form, stay referenced by an internal table that Winforms maintains.  It doesn't get removed from that table until it is disposed.  It doesn't get disposed until you or the user closes the window.  That table has a back-door, Control.FromHandle() uses it.

Comment: @HansPassant Do you know where in the reference source that happens? I was trying to look it up to answer this question but could not find where that internal table insertion is. EDIT: nevermind, found it. `NativeWindow.AddWindowToTable(` (the function`NativeWindow.AssignHandle(` calls it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When settingsButton_Click exits, all reference to settingsForm is lost, but because settingsForm itself has not closed, the garbage collector won't clean it up, at least not until the settingsForm object is closed.  It is okay to code it that way--but you should be careful, also, as the application itself could close, but leave the settingsForm hanging (preventing the application from closing completely).